# Comment peut-on dire « peace out » en français ?

Tags: traduction, anglais, grammaire, expressions-idiomatiques

Notez que je ne veux pas dire simplement *au revoir*.

En anglais, [*peace out*](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=peace%20out) signifie *good-bye*.

Comment: Please explain the usage of unusual English phrases inside your question. At the very least add a link to a definition or to some context that use it.

Comment: Tu devrais ajouter une explication des différents sens de cette expression pour compléter ta question.

Comment: Please don't be cross with me. I simply (innocently) assumed everyone was familiar with it.

Comment: I had a look to the Urban Dictionary. Are you referring to the definitions 2-1) and 2-2)?

Comment: Yes, I do. Exactly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suite aux commentaires sous ta question:

Le sens *c ya later* de l'expression peut être traduit par *ciao*, ou encore *a+* (pour *à plus tard*). Il y a bien d'autres façons de traduire *c ya later*, ces deux-ci étant probablement les plus courantes, du moins ici à Paris. Aucune traduction, à ma connaissance, ne s'approche de la traduction littérale.

Quant au sens *fuck off* de *peace out*, ce pourrait être *tire toi*, *barre toi*, *casse toi*, *va te faire voir*, *va te faire foutre*. Ce qui est à peu de choses près l'équivalent de *piss off*. Attention, les deux dernières versions sont très violentes, les trois premières étant "seulement" très impolies. Ici aussi, il existe bien d'autres façons d'exprimer tout cela en argot. Je m'en tiens aux classiques.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the context but “*va en paix*” or “*allez en paix*” might fit in some situations.

Answer (score 0):

You could say "Reste Gettho" just some argo really, some friend in Paris say "prend soin" as in "prend soin de toi" can be understood as "vas en paix, reste en paix dans ta vie, prend soin de toi, garde la paix autour de toi" = "prend soin"